# Activator.CreateInstance slow performance

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, com

Connecting to a com object takes 7 seconds.
How to improve performance?

[image]

Comment: CAUTION. This is during a debugging session. You'll need an actual profiler to get what this sentence costs during regular run-time.....

Comment: The constructor is likely to be taking up the time. Newing up the class by itself is also probably slow. I doubt the entire 7 seconds is taken up by activator. You need to profile the constructor to find out why it's taking so long.

Comment: So how does this compare to `new ()` ? You can try that to check if the issue is caused by reflection or by constructor doing long running work.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't compare object instantiation time between COM and non-COM.  An object in COM is not the same as an object in .NET. A COM object could be quite "heavy" with intricate aggregation (not quite the same in .NET). There could be extensive dependencies on native DLLs. COM uses reference counting; .NET uses GC.  I've not seen 7 second delays with our work so I doubt `Activator.CreateInstance` is directly to blame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. It was in the debugging session